# Cannot connect to the MySQL database

Tags: php, mysql, database

This is my config.php file which I am using for the database connection. I am using WAMP server for the database and table creation. My database name is **project** and I have **customer_info** table on it. I don't know what to write in the password column as there is no mention of password in phpmyadmin.

```
<?php
define("MYSQLUSER","customer_info");
define("MYSQLPASS","Password1");
define("HOSTNAME","localhost");
define("MYSQLDB","project");
function db_connect(){
$conn = @new mysqli(HOSTNAME,MYSQLDB);
if($conn -> connect_error) {
die('Connect Error: ' . $conn -> connect_error);
}return $conn;
} 
?>
```

Comment: If you haven't set password for your phpmyadmin, the password should be empty. The user is "root".

Comment: Hi, So you've install a MySQL service instance on the PC where you're running apache? When you created the MySQL instance you should have created a "root" account with a password or something similar. That's the username and password. What is the exception you're getting?

Comment: You should also provide user and password for your connection. See http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_connect.asp. try with user: "root", password: "".

Comment: In this code `$conn = @new mysqli(HOSTNAME,MYSQLDB);` you are not providing username and password.
See OOP part.
http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_connect.asp

Comment: Might be your username is wrong, check that, default is root with no password.
<?php
define("MYSQLUSER","root");
define("MYSQLPASS","");
define("HOSTNAME","localhost");
define("MYSQLDB","project");
function db_connect(){
$conn = new mysqli(HOSTNAME, MYSQLUSER, MYSQLPASS, MYSQLDB);
if($conn -> connect_error) {
die('Connect Error: ' . $conn -> connect_error);
}return $conn;
} 
?>

Answer (score 0):

```
$conn = new mysqli('localhost', 'my_user', 'my_password', 'my_db');
```

the object creation should be like this. You are using wrong parameters sequence.

Answer (score 0):

You have configured your database on MySql server and you are accessing it via PHPMyAdmin (just to help you with terminology).
Your config file should be edited this way:

```
<?php
define("MYSQLUSER","root");
define("MYSQLPASS","");
define("HOSTNAME","localhost");
define("MYSQLDB","project");
function db_connect(){
$conn = @new mysqli(HOSTNAME,MYSQLDB);
if($conn -> connect_error) {
die('Connect Error: ' . $conn -> connect_error);
}return $conn;
} 
?>
```